# Exporting from a collection called genre all documents where book_id if it is contained in the book collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql, export, aggregate, nosql-aggregation

I've been stuck on this for about 6 hours now and I'm struggling to find any help on export using mongoDB compass. I have two collections called Books and Genre. They both contain a field called book_id. The genre collection contains documents which I don't need. I only want to extract the documents in the genre collection which have a corresponding book ID in the Book collection. The book_id in the book collection is a string and stored as an integer in genre collection.

Genre Collection:

```
_id: ObjectId('')
genres: Array
book_id: 5
```

Book Collection:

```
_id: ""
book_id: "1823092"
```

I tried using the lookup aggregate pipeline but have no experience with using mongodb so iam struggling immensely if anyone could help it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to return only the `Genre` documents that have a corresponding `book_id` in the `Books` collection.

```js
db.Genre.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Books",
      "let": {
        "book_idStr": {"$toString": "$book_id"}
      },
      "as": "books",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": ["$$book_idStr", "$book_id"]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gt": [{"$size": "$books"}, 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unset": "books"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wmSpSwoQnyR) with some made up data.